# Making an entire LaTeX document size 48 or larger, including math equations

Tags: fontsize

I need to write in size 48 in LaTeX, so far I am making everything larger using the `\Huge` command (I need it bigger than that), but it time consuming and frustrating to do that though. I am sure there is an easier way but so far size 48 has been rejected by LaTeX.

Comment: After `\begin{document}`, `\fontsize{48pt}{52pt}\selectfont` where the `52pt` sets the default `\baselineskip`.

Comment: What about reducing the geometry of your page so that the font *seems* bigger when you fit to page/screen?

Comment: the easiest thing is to use 12pt on 1/4 sized paper, then just scale up the pdf for printing or display

Comment: if you use a scalable font family such as latin modern you can can specify any size you want, but cm by default has restricted sizes unless you put `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` at the top of the document

Comment: You should also be aware that, depending on what you're typesetting, font sizes that are "large when compared to the textblock" can produce ugly results and overfull boxes.

Comment: depending on the font you use, the shapes of the letters (and some other characters) may change (get relatively narrower) when you use large sizes.  scaling up a pdf is the easiest way to avoid this, as already suggested.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `geometry` for this and its `mag` option; the value 4000 means “multiply everything by 4”.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[mag=4000,a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

This is a document containing math
\[
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}
\]
printed on A0 paper at 48pt size.

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Note the page dimensions reported in the info window

[image]

If you have to fit the 48pt sized document in A1 paper, use `a5paper` in the options to `geometry`.